# Scheduling code execution on thread that created class instance

Tags: java, multithreading, observer-pattern

I have a class that derives from `Observable` and does some background work. From time to time, this worker thread posts back work using a `volatile` member variable. However, I'd also like the thread that created the instance to call `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()` whenever this variable changes. I cannot do this directly from the worker thread for thread safety reasons.

How can I let a worker thread execute code (such as `notifyObservers()`) on the instance-creating thread?

Comment: Note that the `notifyObservers()` will occur in the thread that called it.

Comment: That's why I wanted to call `notifyObservers()` from the thread that created the instance.

Comment: Have your worker thread post events to a queue, and have your creator thread get notifications from this queue and notify the observers each time a notification is retrieved.

Comment: That event queue concept is new to me. Could you provide me with a minimal example?

Comment: The javadoc of BlockingQueue contains a typical example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: If I understand `BlockingQueue` correctly, the consumer thread blocks while it is waiting for information. Since the class instance was created on the main thread (which is supposed to do other things while the producer is doing work), I cannot use it. Isn't there a mechanism like Android's [runOnUIThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) that I can use to trigger `notifyObservers` on the thread that created the instance?

Comment: You first need to address the question of where, in your instance-creating thread, setChanged and notifyObservers will be executed.  You can't arbitrarily interrupt another thread's execution and insert some code for it to run;  the instance-creating thread must poll something (like a Queue) and must choose to execute code in response to the polling.  Calling the BlockingQueue.poll method is a good way to do that.